# Oracle "Payment Term Days" column in Oracle Contract module. (Oracle E-Business Suite Release 12.1.3)

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope somebody will be able to help. I have no problems finding Payment Terms on the Supplier Header and Site level columns in the database, but I am not able to locate "Payment Term Days" that are entered when a contract is created with a supplier in Oracle.
I have checked: APPS.OKC_REP_CONTRACT_PARTIES and APPS.OKC_REP_CONTRACTS_ALL with no luck! I am using Oracle E-Business Suite Release 12.1.3

Could anyone please help? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: This question is specific to some unknown (to us) application.  I do know that OKC (as in OKC_REP_CONTRACT_PARTIES) is located in the southwest United States, not located in the UK.

Comment: @EdStevens Sorry... I am fairly new to all this. I have updated my questions with the Oracle version info: Oracle Database 11g EE Extreme Perf Release 11.2.0.4.0. I am using Oracle SQL Developer (Version 20.2.0.175). Do I need to include any more info? Thank you.

Comment: Oracle Database is a tool that can be used to store any data you like - you could make a database of your children's toys, or a database tracking the rollout of a vaccine. The database tables you're seeing are created by a tool that is built *using* Oracle database, but there's no way to tell just by looking at it what structure it stores its data in.

Comment: It's not a matter of what version of the Oracle database is involved.  It's a matter of what _application_ is storing its data in the oracle database.  It is the _application_ that creates the table to its needs.  It is the _application_ that determines how data is stored in the database.  Your screenshot is a window that is created and populated by the _application_.  Your question has to do with how the _application_ works, and we don't even know the name of that application.

Comment: Add Oracle-EBS tag.Run this query to find your apps version `SELECT RELEASE_NAME FROM FND_PRODUCT_GROUPS;`.

Comment: @Suresh + All, thank you for your patience! The release name is 12.1.3, the application I am using is Oracle E-Business Suite.

Comment: @Adrian Unfortunately Oracle removed eTRM from public.Follow this [discussion](https://www.toolbox.com/tech/question/payment-terms-query-071812/).

Comment: @Suresh Thank you. I have actually found it myself! It's here: APPS.OKC_REP_CONTRACTS_ALL in column ATTRIBUTE8 :) Found it by pure chance. I have tested it and it works.